# Jquery selector returning a random " in my function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

https://github.com/rajien2/Itunes

Hey guys,

I've been running my head into a wall for the past day now, this is a class project and I went outside of the requirements just to play with the google API. My function works, if you pass a string into the searchTube('bob') if will find the first video and pop up a youtube windows. The goal is to have this happen when you click on the cover art, now the issue I'm running into is I want to pass in the title of the song and the artist name. However, I get a random " in my return? Now I believe[image] this is due to the spaces, because when I just use the title and pick a title that has spaces the same result... Any idea how I can resolve this issue?

[image: DevTools results]

```
//Do Not Modify the getMusic function
function getMusic() {
    var artist = document.getElementById('artist').value;
    itunes.getMusicByArtist(artist).then(drawSongs);
}







function drawSongs(songList) {
    console.log(songList);

    var container = $('#music-container')
    container.html('')
    songList.forEach(function (song) {

let myItem = song.title
console.log(myItem)


        var card = `
<div class='col-md-6'>
    <p class='h4 text-center' href='${song.url}'>${song.title}</p>
    <p class='h5 text-center' href='${song.url}'>${song.artist}</p>
            <img onclick=searchTube(${song.title} ${song.artist})  class='center-block' src='${song.albumArt}'>
            <div>
            <audio controls class='center-block'>
                <source  src="${song.preview}" type="audio/mpeg"> 
                Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio>
            </div>
</div>
    `

        container.append(card)
        myInfo = ''
    })
}
```

Youtube searchTube function

```
function tplawesome(e, t) { res = e; for (var n = 0; n < t.length; n++) { res = res.replace(/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g, function (e, r) { return t[n][r] }) } return res }


function searchTube(item) {

    // get fourm input
    q = item //$('#query').val()

    //run request on api
    $.get(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search", {
            part: 'snippet',
            type: 'video',
            q: q,
            maxResults: 1,
            order: 'viewCount',
            key: 'AIzaSyD9YPjBHHTiMX_MpqKySSwIIGlxL1zuD9o'
        },
        function (data) {
            console.log(data.items);
            $.each(data.items, function (index, item) {
                $.get('item.html', function (data) {
                    $('#results').append(tplawesome(data, [{ 'title': item.snippet.title, 'videoid': item.id.videoId }]))
                })
                //$('#results').append(item.id.videoId + ' ' + item.snippet.title + '<br>')
            })
            //$('results').append(item.id.videoId + ' ' + data.snippet.title + '<br>');


            $('#my_popup').popup({
                opacity: 0.3,
                transition: 'all 0.3s'
            });


        }
    );
}


//searchTube(test);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not correctly escaping the `searchTube(${song.title} ${song.artist})` part of your code. Since you want to pass a string as the method parameter, you should signal this parameter as a string. Do this by enclosing your parameters into `''`.

You will end up with:

```
<img onclick="searchTube('${song.title} ${song.artist}')"  class='center-block' src='${song.albumArt}'>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that because you left the quotes out of your HTML, the browser tried to add them in sensible places. (When it reaches the space, it doesn't know that you actually meant more things to be part of that attribute value.)

Instead of this:

```
<img onclick=searchTube(${song.title} ${song.artist})
```

Try this:

```
<img onclick="searchTube('${song.title} ${song.artist}')"
```